# Refactoring Model Methods in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, methods

A common idiom that my camp uses in rails is as follows:

```
def right_things(all_things, value)
    things = []
    for thing in all_things
       things << thing if thing.attribute == value
    end
    return things
end
```

how can I make this better/faster/stronger?

thx

-C

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def right_things(all_things, value)
    all_things.select{|x| x.attribute == value}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your things are ActiveRecord models and you only need the items selected for your current purpose, you may, if you're using Rails 2.0 (? definitely 2.1) or above, find `named_scope`s useful.

```
class Thing
  named_scope :rightness, lambda { |value| :conditions => ['attribute = ?', value] }
end
```

So you can say

```
Thing.rightness(123)
```

, which is (in this case) similar to

```
Thing.find_by_attribute(123)
```

in that it boils down to a SQL query, but it's more easily chainable to modify the SQL. If that's useful to you, which it may not be, of course...